# Add "on click" event to single (dynamic) element inside jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, jquery-plugins

I'm having an issue with adding an on click event inside a jQuery plugin.

The following is firing on all elements (should only fire on a single element), event is not applied to dynamic elements (it should) - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nznarxkf/4/)** :

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var settings = { ... }
    var methods = {
        init : function() {
            $(document).on('click', element, function () {
                element.css('background', 'red');
            });
        }
    };
    return methods.init();
};
```

I need the onclick event inside the plugin `settings.event` (`hover`, `click`, ...).

**How can I bind a dynamic on click event inside a jquery plugin with out it firing on every element ?**

Comment: I can see event is applied to both dynamic and static li's

Comment: When you click on an `<li>` the background for that element should change, not all of them. The dynamic `<li>`'s background never changes.

Comment: You mean on click of dynamic <li> right?

Comment: Yep, dynamic or not the background should change only for the element clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stay more close to the common [**jQuery plugin pattern**](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/).

```
// method is an (optional) string to call a special method on each element
// options is an (optional) object to add or overwrite properties of the defaults
$.fn.myPlugin = function(method, options) {
    if (typeof method == 'object') options = method, method = null;
    var settings,
        defaults = {
            events: {click: function() {$(this).css({backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor});}},
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            border: '2px solid black',
            /* all your defaults here */
        },
        methods: {
            giveBorder: function() {$(this).css({border: settings.border});}
            /* all your named methods here, you can use values from settings inside*/
        }
    settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options); // merge defaults and options together
    // now apply a function to each element and return the whole collection
    // if there's a valid method do this
    if (method && methods[method]) return this.each(methods[method]);
    // otherwise do the initializing function
    else return this.each(function(i, elem) { // this 'is' the initializing function
        // put in here all you want to do with each element on init
        $.each(settings.events, function(evt, func) { // apply the event handler to each element
            if (typeof func == 'function')elem.on(evt, func);
        })
    })
};
```

When you now do on the li-elements `$('li').myPlugin()` all single elems get a click-handler attached. But `$('li')` is **not live**, it holds only the elems beeing in the DOM when it's called (old versions of jQuery had a `.live()`-function but that was deprecated and removed).

So when you want to initialize a newly created elem with your plugin do it this way:

```
var alllis = $('li').myPlugin();
var newli = $('<li>Dynamic</li>').myPlugin(); // now it has also a click-handler
$('ul').append(newli); // now it's added to the DOM
alllis.add(newli); // this way you can add it to the jQuery collection of all li
```

Here' is a working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nznarxkf/51/), and you should play around with following to evaluate the possibilities of this pattern:

```
var newli2 = $('<li>DynamicGreen</li>').myPlugin({backgroundColor: 'green'});
var newli3 = $('<li>DynamicMouseover</li>').myPlugin(
    {events: {click: 'none', mouseover: function() {$(this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'})} }}
);
newli3.myPlugin('giveBorder');
$('ul').append(newli2, newli3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the event is firing on all static elements is because when you call `$('li').myPlugin();`, the object that is getting passed to the plugin is a nodelist, not a single node. Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/nznarxkf/45/)** works better for the elements that the plugin is applied to.

```
init : function() {
            element.each(
                function(i, el) { 
                    $(el).on('click', function () {
                        $(el).toggleClass('bg_red');
                    });
                });
        }
```

Also, note that when you pass in the element here `$(document).on('click', element, function (e) {`, it is not scoping the handler to this element the way I think you are trying to do. `.on()` only uses selectors (i.e. strings) for that. In this case, `element` is getting passed in in event.data, and is going unused.

As far as why it doesn't work on the dynamically added one, I am not sure, but I suspect it may be a scoping issue.